# Forking a Windows shell with new environment variable

Tags: windows, go

I'm able to do this on linux (bash) using:

```
os.Setenv("TESTKEY", "TestVal")
syscall.Exec(os.Getenv("SHELL"), []string{os.Getenv("SHELL")}, syscall.Environ())
```

Is it possible to do something similar in powershell? I've tried various alternatives but they all fail silently, e.g.:

```
syscall.Exec("PowerShell", []string{"-Command", "Set-Item", "-path", "env:TESTKEY", "-value", "TestVal"}, env)
```

Comment: If you just need to execute commands, try using [`os/exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec) instead of `syscall`.

Answer (score 1):

**thanks @Adrian** - the following works:

```
cmd := exec.Command("PowerShell")
cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(),"TESTKEY=TestVal")
cmd.Run()
```